# parallax.js + js fadein/out = no joy after first <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, parallax.js

I am using parallax.js to animate a series of elements on a homepage. I searched for code that would allow me to add a simple "slider" effect to the elements as well.

Everything seems to be working properly, except that after the first *li*, the parallax effect only works horizontally. On *li* #1, the element hovers as expected, following the mouse in every direction.

Here's a link to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sdeviva/t6uwq/1/

Here's a link to the revised jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sdeviva/t6uwq/5/

```
var scene = document.getElementById('scene');
var parallax = new Parallax(scene);

var scene = document.getElementById('scene2');
var parallax = new Parallax(scene2);


(function($) {
$.fn.ezslide = function ( options ) {
var defaults = {
        fadeIn  : 1000,
        fadeOut : 1000,
        delay   : 500
    },
    settings = $.extend( defaults, options ),
    $this = this,
    cur = 0,
    fadeIt = function( which ) {
        var li = $this.find('li');

        cur = which = (which >= li.length) ? 0 : which;

        li.fadeOut( settings.fadeOut );
        li.eq( which )
          .delay( settings.fadeOut )
          .fadeIn( settings.fadeIn, function(){
            setTimeout(function() { 
                cur++;
                fadeIt( cur ); 
            }, settings.delay);
        });

    };

fadeIt( cur );
};

$('ul.scene').ezslide({
    fadeIn  : 600,
    fadeOut : 600,
    delay   : 3000
    });
})(jQuery);
```

**EDIT:** I sort of fixed this. I don't really know what I'm doing, so there's probably a cleaner way. But, I realized that the parallax effect was only being applied once to the first list item. The script that makes each item fade in wasn't getting the benefit of the parallax.js script.

SO - I put each fading element into its own ul, with a unique id, and a shared class. By some miracle, this actually works. But let me know if there's a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting one.  The issue is that the parallax code sets the very first layer to `position: relative` and all others to `position: absolute`.  This has the effect of making the parent `ul` have the dimensions of only the first layer.  This is normally fine, except that when you display any element other than the first, the first is hidden.  This causes the `ul` to have 0 height.  The parallax depends on the height of the scene, as a result no height means no vertical movement.

You can fix the issue by applying a fixed height to your `ul`:

```
#scene{
    height: 128px;    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t6uwq/7/

You can find greater detail on the motion calculation in the [documentation on github](https://github.com/wagerfield/parallax#understanding-layer-motion-calculations).

Comment: In practice, when I made this update, it looks like the CSS is stripped out - and I think it's the parallax.js, but it could be Wordpress. So, I had to add the style for height within the HTML, instead of external stylesheet. I'm not sure what the difference is from jsfiddle to my site.